# how to read from workspace\generate signal repeatably each time a rising edge appears

Tags: simulink

I would like to use a clock or a pulse generator and for each rising edge I would like to generte\read from worksapce some signal.

When I am using a triggered subsystem it only reacts to the first edge and doesn't do it repeatedly

[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOCpQ.png)

[scope output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlkHi.png)

Comment: Tell us/show us exactly what you are doing and trying to achieve.  Using the MATLAB workspace for data transfer is almost always a bad idea, so what you are doing is most likely not appropriate, but you haven't given us enough detail to know for sure.  Note that triggered system **_do_** execute at every trigger, so it's what you have in the subsystem that is not working, it's not the actual triggering itself.

Comment: added some photos